# PHP - Installing Composer - failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: php, composer-php

I am attempting to use the [Composer Dependency Manager](http://getcomposer.org/) for PHP, but I am experiencing the following issue when I use the Composer-Setup.exe (Win32 installer).

```
Download failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. 
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. 
Download failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. 
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. 
Download failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. 
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. 
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.`
```

I followed the advice on several other stackoverflow threads for that error, and I've checked some other forums. In my php.ini, I have made sure I have the following options:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

I also tried the [manual installation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer) of Composer, which asks you to execute:

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

I get the same error from that. However, If I remove "/installer", it can retrieve the source. I have verified that that the "/installer" URL works. What configuration could cause this behavior? I'm running PHP 5.4 on 32-bit Windows 7.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Hi Seldaek. I've tried both behind a proxy and not. It's the same result both times. However, I have defined the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables.

Comment: During troubleshooting, I removed the proxy variables and received the same error messages, so I don't think they're a factor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue was actually the proxy variables. While the console was picking up the changes, PHP required a system restart to pick it up. So unsetting the environment variables and restarting allowed the Composer installer to retrieve the required files. Thanks Seldaek for your recommendation to check the proxy.

Comment: You could avoid a system restart by restarting the webserver.

Comment: did u remove all the environment variables in this case..?
I am facing the same issue..pls help me

Comment: I was having this issue within php: `readfile('http://example.com')`, and restarting apache solved the issue. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Below is the Error,which normally occurs if your proxy settings are there]

**Solution 1**

- Ensure you have connectivity try ping www.google.com

**Solution 2**

```
- Remove Proxy settings ,they could be ones causing it,if outside a corporate network
```

**Solution 3**

- Add the corporate proxy setting if on a corporate network

  - set http_proxy=http://your_proxy:your_port
  - set http_proxy=http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
  - set https_proxy=https://your_proxy:your_port
  - set https_proxy=https://username:password@your_proxy:your_port

Answer (score -7):

```
mysqli_connect('root','', 'localhost', 'people');
```

You are passing root in as hostname.

try this

```
mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'people');
```

this will connect to localhost with username root passwoord "" and default database people.

maybe better to change localhost with 127.0.0.1

Comment: Nagendra, I removed the proxy environment variables mentioned on 12/27/2012, and it worked.