# Composer not updating all of a sudden

Tags: php, laravel, dependencies, runtime-error, composer-php

The only thing I remember doing different was canceling a `composer update` command before it started updating any dependencies.

I get this error if I try `composer self-update`:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or
service not known
```

I'm guessing it's an issue with composer itself.

EDIT: `composer diag` fails on 3 things: http connectivity to packagist, github.com oauth access, and checking composer version.

Comment: try `composer diag` and see what you get

Comment: I know it's trivial, but also check firewall and antivirus software, especially if you're on a WIndows machine. Try to temporarily turn everything off.

Comment: @haakym IT fails on 3 things: http conn. to packagist, github.com oauth access, and checking composer version.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Tried it with no luck.

Comment: alexey-mezenin makes a good point, I once had k9 web filter stop composer

Comment: @jstudios you might want to update the output of `composer diag` into your question as it might help someone solve your issue. Also if you're behind a proxy you would need to make sure you've got that all set up properly.

Comment: similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000646/php-installing-composer-failed-to-open-stream-php-network-getaddresses-get  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366698/installing-laravel-dependencies-with-composer-not-working  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702081/laravel-dependency-cannot-be-retrieved-via-composer-alternative-for-getting-l4 and you may want to look at this: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2169

Answer (score 3):

I restarted the computer and it fixed it...The app is running on a Docker container so maybe just restarting the container itself would have helped, but I wanted to go all the way.

Comment: I had to reboot the MAC as well. Didn't worked with the docker container restart.